# how to selected data based on several conditions mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-select-db

i have a table called my_table like this

```
+------------+--------+--------+
|  product   | type_1 | type_2 |
+------------+--------+--------+
| Banana     | A1     | B1     |
| Banana     | B1     | B2     |
| Watermelon | A      | B3     |
| Orange     | B      | B4     |
+------------+--------+--------+
```

so i want to make query IF the product banana, then it returns type_2, and the other product return type_1

so the expected results is just like this

```
+------------+------+
|  product   | type |
+------------+------+
| Banana     | B1   |  
| Banana     | B2   |  
| Watermelon | A    |  
| Orange     | B    | 
+------------+------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CASE to select the column you want.

```
SELECT product, (CASE produt
                     WHEN 'Banana' THEN type_2
                     ELSE type_1
                 END) as type

FROM my_table
```